# Java is crashing my Pi

Tags: java

I am running ScreenConnect on some Rasp Pis and the Pi eventually hangs up and then it will crash and require a reboot to allow ScreenConnect to work again.

This is in the ScreenConnect logs:

```
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x7657407c, pid=1381, tid=1695765600
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0-b132) (build 1.8.0-b132)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.0-b70 mixed mode linux-arm )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x16507c]  CounterDecay::do_method(Method*)+0x14
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# //hs_err_pid1381.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Finalizer"
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:459)
        at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
        at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1163)

/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Finalizer"
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:459)
        at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
        at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1163)

/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Finalizer"
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/rt.jar: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

Is this more an issue with Java or an issue with the actual client?

Would limiting the amount of MEM Java can use fix this? I tried using export to push limiting options but export does not work on Pi.

Answer (score 3):

Have you deleted any JDK files recently? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675875/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm-macosx) suggests you may be missing some files from your java installation. Just in case you could try reinstalling java.

Comment: I can try that but I've not deleted anything. I did an apt-get install oracle-java8* and left it like that

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible solution available here - https://community.openhab.org/t/openhab-crashes-sometimes-multiple-times-a-day-sometimes-once-a-week/6801

Comment: The link may answer the question, but all of the essential bits need to be included in your answer.